# Cannot connect to new project with SparkleShare client on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, ssh, 64-bit, sparkleshare

I followed the install/create steps on the front page of the [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org) website, and when I do `dazzle create media`, I get the following back:

Project "media" was successfully created.

The address is correct (storage@ip.add.re.ss)
And the path is correct (/home/storage/media)

I run ssh on notport 22 (successfully with WinSCP, pscp, and PuTTY off the same machine and others), so I added the `:<port>` to the connect field in my Windows client (runnign on Windows 7 x64 current patches).

The client (0.9.2) then waits interminably at a smidge of green in the progress bar.

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What version of Sparkleshare are you using? Did you also try other than Win7/x64 platforms? Is PuTTY able to connect to the host? And are you running any firewall blocking outbound connections?

Comment: @gertvdijk - 0.9.2. After talking to one of the lead devs on their irc channel, it looks like a known issue that is fixed in the next release which is not out yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With assistance from the devs of SparkleShare, found the issue (and am waiting on an official fix while implementing a workaround below).

In `~\AppData\Roamin\sparkleshare\debug_log.txt` is the following:

```
11:57:53 | Controller | ssh-agent started, PID=6972
11:57:54 | Auth | Imported key 'C:\Users\wmyers\AppData\Roaming\sparkleshare\2012-09-20 11h20.key'
11:57:54 | Auth | The following keys may be used: 
2048 5f:8c:51:d7:53:d1:61:98:f6:bd:68:56:cc:ce:d2:d0 C:\Users\wmyers\AppData\Roaming\sparkleshare\2012-09-20 11h20.key (RSA)
11:59:18 | Fetcher | C:\Users\wmyers\SparkleShare\.tmp\media | Fetching folder: ssh://storage@176.9.40.74:8110/home/storage/media
11:59:18 | Auth | Fetching host key for 176.9.40.74
11:59:20 | Auth | Skipping fingerprint check
11:59:20 | Auth | Accepted host key for 176.9.40.74
11:59:20 | Fetcher | Failed creating fingerprint: Index was outside the bounds of the array.   at SparkleLib.SparkleFetcherBase.GetFingerprint(String public_key)
11:59:21 | Cmd | .tmp | git clone --progress --no-checkout --depth=1 "ssh://storage@176.9.40.74:8110/home/storage/media" "C:\Users\wmyers\SparkleShare\.tmp\media"
```

The key line is the one at 11:59:20 with "Fetcher" at the front.

There is a fix officially being released shortly that addresses proper importation of the server's public SSH key. The current workaround is to manually copy the contents of the server's `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` into `~\.ssh\known_hosts` on the client machine.

If that does not work for you, you need to wait for the next release after 0.9.2.

Also, apparently this is only related to running ssh on a non-standard port.